# How to sum the hour of time based on same id with mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I never done a time summary before. But the idea is to sum all the time in hour from DB. Based on the same id and time period. For the sample data below. I want to know how many hour in which id '57' working in month 4. Only when there're starting time(chkin_type=1) and ending time (chkin_type=2).

So I know that I have to find the time diff with
`DATEDIFF(hour, time1, time2)`. But I don't know how to loop through the last row.

**Sample data**

[image]

I can do the select.
`select * from checkin_db where uid='57' and month(dtime)='4'`

But I stuck here:

1. How to select `dtime` where `chkin_type`=1 to compare with `chkin_type`=2
2. How to loop the result and sum the total time in hours with `datediff`?

Comment: Can you edit your question and share your simple data as text

Comment:  Please never post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data; Please see [Why should I tag my RDBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759) and edit the tags as appropriate.

Comment: Why do you give integer data as string literals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data has to be pivoted and then it is possible to calculate the time differences and then sum them.
Since MySql lacks *pivot* functionality it must be simulated using *CASE WHEN* together with an aggregate function (in this case *max()*)

So the inner query '*pvt*' selects the wanted data and pivots it.
The second-level query '*mins*' calculates the time difference in minutes for each day and sums the results.
Finally the outer query splits the time in hour and minutes.

Keep in mind that all this can work only if the two time values are in the same day.

```
SELECT total_minutes DIV 60 as hours, total_minutes MOD 60 as minutes
FROM (

    SELECT sum(timestampdiff(MINUTE, time1, time2)) as total_minutes
    FROM (

        SELECT date(dtime) as date,
               max(CASE WHEN ckin_type = 1 THEN time(dtime) ELSE NULL END) as time1,
               max(CASE WHEN ckin_type = 2 THEN time(dtime) ELSE NULL END) as time2
        FROM checkin_db
        WHERE uid='57' and month(dtime)='4'
        GROUP BY date(dtime)
    
    ) pvt
    
   WHERE time1 IS NOT NULL
     AND time2 IS NOT NULL
     
) mins;
```

Comment: Your answer is working. Thank you for your kindness. I'll give this a study so I'll learn new thing.